# RibbonButton vs Button - different results when rejecting changes in DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, infragistics

I have a `XamDataGrid` with a `DataTable` as a source:

```
dataPresenter:XamDataGrid Grid.Row="1" DataSource="{Binding TestData}"     GroupByAreaLocation="None"
```

I'm using MVVM Light to handle commands. In my view model I have:

```
public class MainViewModel: ViewModelBase
{            
    public RelayCommand OnCancel { get; set; }
    private DataTable _testData;
    public DataTable TestData
    {
        get { return _testData; }
        set { Set(() => TestData, ref _testData, value); }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        OnCancel = new RelayCommand(Cancel);
    }
    private void Cancel()
    {
        TestData.RejectChanges();
    }
}
```

To handle the commands I want to use the Windows Ribbon:

```
<r:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" >
    <r:RibbonTab >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <r:RibbonButton Label="Get Data" Command="{Binding OnGetData}"/>
            <r:RibbonButton Label="Cancel" Command="{Binding OnCancel}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </r:RibbonTab>
</r:Ribbon>

<!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="Get Data" Command="{Binding OnGetData}" Margin="0,0,20,0" Height="40"/>
    <Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding OnCancel}" Height="40"/>
</StackPanel>-->
```

I'm getting different behavior when using the `RibbonButton` vs just the `Button`. What I want is to reject any changes made the `XamDataGrid`. When I use the Button, the changes are rejected in the `DataTable` and the `XamDataGrid` updates accordingly. When I change the code so the `RibbonButton` executes the `Cancel` method this does not happen. The behavior seems sporadic. The `XamDataGrid` is not properly updated even though I can see changes have been reject in the `DataTable`. Why would this be happening?